# web_accessible_resources doesnt works

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

manifest.json:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "*://google.com"],
      "js": ["js/google.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": [ "*://facebook.com/*"],
      "js": ["js/facebook.js"]
    }
  ],
"web_accessible_resources": ["js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"]
```

So, first and second sites needs jquery and some little scripts (google.js and facebook.js). I use `web_accessible_resources` because in Chrome 29 I have error: `GET chrome-extension://invalid/`.

Now I having new erros - in google.js and facebook.js - `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

I try

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js");
```

But the same error - jquery doesnt work on google.com and facebook.com (matches). How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: You have to add jQuery to the list "js" array of the content scripts.

Comment: @RobW In first version - I done it, but I have error - `GET chrome-extension://invalid/`.

Comment: That's because you're trying to inject the script. Put jQuery in the "js" array in the manifest file.

Comment: `Denying load of chrome-extension://mkackiikdgbbdchcngobjmmbkgclfema/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension. ` + `GET chrome-extension://invalid/  `. If I deleted jquery from content scripts - `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: That error is harmless. If you want to get rid of it, edit `jquery-2.0.3.min.js` jQuery file, and remove `//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-2.0.3.min.map`.

Comment: May be it bug in Chrome 29, in 28 all works (js in content scripts). Thanks.